# Wiring for basement - do I need conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement, light-fixture

I am finishing my basement with 2x4 frames. I have lots of **single conductor** wires (standard and solid core) from the old unfinished basement. I am wondering can I use these **single conductor** wires among the **2x4 frames** **without conduits**? That is can I just use three bare single conductor wires (white, red, green) without any other protection, such as conduit? Just like the way we use Romex among the frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, single wires can't be used unless part of a Chapter 3 wiring method in the NEC that calls for their use, such as conduit.  This is specified in 300.3(A):

> **(A) Single Conductors.** Single conductors specified in Table 310.104(A) shall only be installed where part of a recognized wiring method of Chapter 3.

Comment: You've got the right answer, but the wrong reason.  Your [other answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/79974/33), is a better fit.

Comment: @Tester101 -- it's the same Code cite :) I did clean up the explanation a bit though

Answer (score 3):

First, look at the markings on the wires.  There should be a lot of words, and they should repeat every 12 inches.  If you don't see any words, you cannot use that wire at all.  This might happen if the previous installer shucked Romex, though the green wire is a good sign.   If it says THHN or THWN, the wire at least is good.

It will need to be in some kind of conduit, and no more than four circuits per conduit. If it is a multi-wire branch circuit, that counts as one circuit, however since those play so badly with GFCI/AFCI, now is a good time to think about converting that to 2 circuits.

If you have more than 4 circuits or want expansion room, you'll need 2 or more conduits, or pull all the wire and derate it, which is probably what the last guy should have donesince he bunched them all together.  This was a bad installation and you should be on the lookout for other bad work.  If it is a 3-wire 120/240V circuit, that counts as one circuit.

Or you can redo the whole kit 'n' kaboodle in Romex.  Your call. I personally do most of my work in industrial and have no taste for Romex.  It's stiff, you can't use stranded wire, you have to handle ground wires (metallic conduit *is* the grounding path), it's vulnerable to damage, and it's devilishly hard to add circuits or upgrade wire sizes.

There are several ways to lay conduit in places that are not necessarily easy to lay conduit. Ask your local electrical supply house (build a relationship with them, don't just go to them when the big-box doesn't have something, they are very nice and knowledgeable in a way big-box guys just won't be, unless you have the sad situation where the electrical supply house owner went out of business and had to go to work for Home Depot, it happens, but then HD won't stock the stuff he would recommend.)

If you use metallic conduit that means you don't need to pull ground wires through the conduit.  Try to limit yourself to one 90 degree bend between accessible points, it will be easier to pull.  (I usually do a blind push in those cases.) You can legally have four 90s but you'll never pull that without proper electrician's pulling tools.   All access points need to be accessible, can't be drywalled over.

What I'm preaching here is the idea of making your house easily DIYa maintainable, so you don't have to hire expensive or difficult work to access all the utilities you need to maintain from time to time.  Think about that as you're designing this thing.

My house, there is literally a tasteful latched cabinet door in the hallway, and if you open it up, there's the backside of the tub/shower faucet. Details like that save you a fortune later.